# AutoMapper Initialize

Tags: c#, automapper

We have an application we are building and we have a DataTranslationLayer that is responsible for translating a database object into a view model object.

Because we do not pass our database objects to the web project we cant initialize in global.asax.  We would need initialize in the DataTranslationLayer.

The issue with that is that when we instantiate the class, it does another initialize and that is now causing issues because AutoMapper is designed to be initialized only once.

So my question is, has anyone implemented a similar solution and what did you do?

Is the solution to create a static class in the DTL that we call on application start or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The static AutoMapper is just a thin layer. You can easily create one or more instances of AutoMapper each with a different configuration.
See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734108/automapper-how-to-map-object-a-to-object-b-differently-depending-on-context/15869916#15869916) for how to do this.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it means that you don't pass in database objects into the web project, but maybe you have a complicated layered architecture. In that case, one way to do this is to use reflection to load up all profiles:

```
    var assembliesToScane = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    var allTypes = assembliesToScan.SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes).ToArray();

    var profiles =
        allTypes
            .Where(t => typeof(Profile).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo()))
            .Where(t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });
```

You don't directly reference any one profile, but just load all Profile's from the current AppDomain.